# Sqlite and fluent nhibernate are so slow together

Tags: wpf, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

Hello I'm usin Fluent Nhibernate and SQLite in my WPF application.
Fluent Nhibernate Version is " fluentnhibernate-NH3.1-1.2 "
and Sqlite version is " 1.0.79 "
My application configuration is

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite" publicKeyToken="DB937BC2D44FF139" culture="neutral"/>        
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.79.0" newVersion="1.0.79.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

The **Problem is that they are working very slow transactions handling 3000 transactions take 10 minutes to be doone **
I used Journal_mode = off and it worked well But When I tried to do **eager loading ** it took 5 minutes for 500 kb of data.

Comment: show us the code you use to process the transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution , in the configuration of the session factory builder method and builschema method there is a line of code that I had to get red of it : showsql instruction was the one slowing the process now my application is capable of doing 72000 insertions per second